# How to calculate dB of a transmitted power

Tags: digital-communications

why if I lose 80% power in the output of a system, Does it mean that I had lost `10×log10(0.2) = -7dB` ?

Comment: is it just me or does this question seem trivial?

Comment: @CyberMen Please see (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @0x90: I'm finding it hard to delete this question because the accepted answer has so many upvotes.  That means lots of people thought the answer was interesting... so perhaps the question isn't as trivial as CyberMen suggests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a system that causes 80% of its input power to be lost, then 20% of the input power will remain at the output. The power gain of the network is therefore:

$$
G = \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} =0.2
$$
$$
G|_{dB} = 10 \log_{10}(G) = 10 \log_{10}(0.2) \approx -7 \text{ dB}
$$